# Maven org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException

Tags: maven-2

I have Maven project with two sub-modules , each module has dependency with xerces2.8.1(for wsdl2java with cxf) .    If i build the sub-modules seperately it builds successfully.

If i build from root module , while building the second sub-module it fails with below exception

```
[INFO] org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apach
e.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
```

Anybody has come across this before?

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: +1 for including the exact error message

Answer (score 40):

You need to add the following to the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</plugin>
```

After that it should work.

Comment: could you please explain the answer? why the codegen plugin needs the inner dependency?

Comment: Because another unsupported version of xerces implementation was being loaded rather than the one the codegen plugin expected.

Comment: For CXF 3.2.1  I used xerces 2.11.0 and it resolved my problem.  The correct version can be found in the cxf-parent pom file.